# Getting extra braces and brackets while recieving json response

Tags: php, curl

I am getting json response from a 3rd party vendor as json reponse which contains some extra brackets and braces example:

```
$data= \GuzzleHttp\json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
```

output is :

```
"description" => """Hey guys,
Adobe Photoshop CS6\n
Apple Final Cut Pro X\n
ScreenFlow"""
```

Or some times like this :

```
)]}' {"key":["
```

**Updated Example:**

```
)]}' {
  "names": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d"
  ],
  "val": "data1",
  "bool": true
}
```

Why this kind of response I am getting ?

Comment: can you post json array?

Comment: @lalithkumar check I have updated in the question

Comment: i'm not sure whether this will help you..just try like $data= \GuzzleHttp\json_decode(trim(curl_exec($ch)),true);

Comment: thanks I tried but , same result @lalithkumar